# how to create a pipe module Angular

Tags: angular

I have a module which is a a group of pipes. When I try to install this module in my app, it says that the xxx pipe is not found

my app.module looks something like this:

```
import { PipesModule } from '@Pricetravel/pipes.module';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    PipesModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Is there a special way to create the pipe module? or a special way to import it?

thanks and greetings!

Comment: have you added declations of your piples in your PipesModule, export of class done ?

Comment: yeah this is my pipe.module :

import { Round } from './components/pipes/round.pipe';
@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    Round
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class PipeModule {
}

Comment: check answer you forgot to include export: propperty in your pipe module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to export your piple classes also , to export pipe classes in you module you have to write name of classes in export property of module.

In your code given in comment you forgot to export that is the reason why you are not getting piple declared in module in another module where you are using piple module.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyFilter],
  imports: [],
  exports:[MyFilter],//export list here 
  providers: []
})
export class PipleModule { }
```

Comment: thank you so much , i choose this as the best anwser because he gaves me an explanation of my error , and again thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

This is example of `pipes.module.ts` :

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UnescapePipe } from './pipes/unescape.pipe';
import { HtmlDecodePipe } from './pipes/html-decode.pipe';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [UnescapePipe, HtmlDecodePipe],
  exports: [UnescapePipe, HtmlDecodePipe]
})
export class PipesModule { }
```